# Delete emails from a list of different senders in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, bulk, sdelete

I need to delete a few thousand emails from various senders in my inbox, I have a list of all the senders in excel, is there anyway I can do this rather than have to manually sort and delete the concerned mails?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Sort "From" , highlight and delete, Repeat.  That will be faster overall than trying to create a rule that has to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all emails from many senders with Rules:
[image]

After moving items to deleted items folder, right-click on the deleted folder and select empty folder, in this way, you can permanently delete them.

Comment: Do you think my reply is helpful? If so, please accept it as answer to help other people.